# problemas con consulta eloquen laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

He intentado traducir esta consulta a **eloquent**, pero aun no me funciona, solo quiero  me que consulte en base a un campo con valores `no null`.

```
select * from usuarios where asignacion is not null;
```

Como puedo lograrlo?

Comment: primer resultado en google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281504/how-do-you-check-if-not-null-with-eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con ayuda del método `whereNotNull()` que recibe la columna donde deseas hacer la comprobación, puedes hacerlo mediante el modelo si es que tienes uno; así

```
$data = User::whereNotNull('asginacion')->get();
```

O con el queryBuilder así

```
$data = \DB::table('usuarios')->whereNotNull('asginacion')->get();
```

Aquí tienes la referencia de la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

Comment: Gracias shadow por la respuesta

Comment: @zereft no hay por que agradecer, siempre que se te pueda apoyar; con gusto lo haré